# PHP : Permission denied while exec("/var/www/au/main") which is a C++ binary

Tags: php, apache

On my terminal, the C++ executable works fine :

```
$ /var/www/au/main
main : No word specified // coustom error message, to stdout
```

But my `index.php` which has

```
echo exec('whoami') . '<br>' ;
exec("/var/www/au/main 2>&1", $output, $return );
echo '<pre>'; print_r($output); echo '</pre>';
echo $return . '<br>';
```

Produces this when run on a browser

```
apache
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 sujay apache 14168 Nov 25 00:48 /var/www/au/main
Array
(
    [0] => sh: /var/www/au/main: Permission denied
)
126
```

I've also checked to see that `exec()` isn't disabled in `php.ini` and have also added `php_admin_flag safe_mode Off` to my httpd.conf but to no avail.

I've also added

```
<Directory "/var/www/au">
AllowOverride None
# Allow open access:
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to my `httpd.conf` file.

Comment: Looks like it executed. You're just not printing the output correctly.

Comment: @Mat, I realised the same just now, but it doesn't seem to be working even after the correction

Comment: @YSC, corrected, still doesn't seem to execute

Comment: `2 > &1` isn't valid syntax, `2>&1` is

Comment: @Mat, Thanks, what went wrong is now shown

Comment: I'd guess the account under which your PHP is running doesn't have filesystem pemission to the script

Comment: @ADyson, how do I check/ correct that ? I've already made it the group owner